# mqtt in C giving Error -1

Tags: c, mqtt, paho

Working on a driver development, I'm try to publish my data with MQtt in C its running but giving me Error code -1 (MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE  [you can see in that picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APzBC.png) )

I installed ActiveMQ broker in my system and test in MQTTbox that its working properly So Im not getting my problem
Thank you

[I'm using that code](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/pubasync.html)

Comment: Do not post pictures of code or error messages, it makes them totally un searchable

Comment: _I'm try to publish my data with MQtt in C_ So, what is the tag [tag:c++] good for? (Please, prevent tag spamming. That's disliked and good for down-votes only.)

Answer (score 0):

AS you can see on https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQMQxrCClasses/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#af33a6d6c0e8a6a747bf39638e0bba36b  #define MQTTCLIENT_FAILURE   -1 Return code: A generic error code indicating the failure of an MQTT client operation."

You should set break point in every occurence of "MQTTClient_publish" in "MQTTClient_publish" function to determine exacly reason why you can not publish. There is only 4 occurences, so it should go easy.

Comment: can you explore it, Sorry I didn't get what you want to say